# Partial Checkout For Specific Users in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, assembla

I am using Tortoise SVN and having SVN service from Assembla. Until today, I worked alone in a project but now I need to get help from some other developers but I don't want them to be able to download all part of my source code. Is it possible to prevent them from checking out whole code? Is there a mechanism for them to download only binaries, not source codes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only talking abt SVN here -- one way of doing this is by using "SVN external", and you may want different files or subdirectories to come from different locations in a repository, or perhaps from different repositories altogether.
Ref : https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't implement this restriction. And this is not Assembla limitation, but Subversion: you can limit access by path, not by file-type

For Assembla, however, you can

- don't grant SVN-access to developer
- place all binaries in "Files" tool (add it, if needed)

Answer (score -1):

If you have distinct projects, you can have different SVN projects inside different Assembla spaces. Users are associated with spaces in Assembla, so you put the project they CAN access in one space, and add them as a user in that space, and you put the project they CAN't access in another space.

But obviously this only works if you are working in separate SVN repos, or you can split your project into different repos.

If you were using GIT, you can set up permissions so certain users can only READ some areas, but can't push changes into those areas. (That doesn't prevent them from cloning the whole repository), but if you aren't worried about sharing the code, you just want to protect certain parts of it, this might be another solution.

Comment: Would be interested to know the reason for the down vote. As somebody who is new to the community, it is frustrating when you try to make a contribution and get beat down.